# Python: add a sublist on each dictionary key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

We have 2 lists with length of list B being n times list A let's say for example the following two

```
A=['name1','name2','name3']
B=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to create a dictionary with keys the list A elements and for values a sub-list of len(B)/len(A) (that will always have no remainder) of list B

In this particular example the desired result would be the following

```
{'name1':[1,2], 'name2':[3,4], 'name3':[5,6]
```

I tried to initialize the keys of my dictionary given list A (maybe this could be done in 1 step? along with values)

```
dct=dict.fromkeys(A,None)
```

I tried to create the sublists doing the following

```
vals=[B[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(B),2)]
```

But i'm having trouble connecting those two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have already discovered list comprehension. But let me introduce you to dictionary comprehension:

```
A=['name1','name2','name3']
B=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

items_per_a = len(B) // len(A)

your_dictionary = {
    n: B[i * items_per_a:(i + 1) * items_per_a]
    for i, n in enumerate(A)
}
```

### Explanation:

First we calculate how many items there are per sublist. We use the `//` integer division operation for this. This assumes that there is always `len(A) * n` items in `B`

```
items_per_a = len(B) // len(A)
```

Within the dict comprehension, first we enumerate `A`, which produces something like this:

```
i, n
----------
0, "name1"
1, "name2"
2, "name3"
```

Using this, we calculate the sub-list, using list slicing, where the start index is the number of sub-lists already taken times the size of the sub-list, and the end index is the start of the next sub-list

```
B[i * items_per_a:(i + 1) * items_per_a]
```

Then we assign to the name key `n` the sublist

```
n: B[i * items_per_a:(i + 1) * items_per_a]
```

Giving us a dictionary like this:

```
{'name1': [1, 2], 'name2': [3, 4], 'name3': [5, 6]}
```

Note, this assumes Python 3.7+

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Extra appreciation for the explanation as well. Thank you very much